# How to prove this simple inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $q \geq 1$.  How can I show that for sufficiently large $x$, we have

$$q( \log(y)- \log(x) ) \leq y-x$$

Whenever $y\geq x$?

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem? It tells you something about $\log (y) - \log (x)$.

Comment: Hint: $\log{y}-\log{x}=\log\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Aha! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), note that:

$$(\ln(x))'=\frac{1}{x}$$

so:
$$\frac{|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|}{|x-y|}=\frac{1}{\theta}$$

where $\theta \in (x,y)$. For sufficiently large $x$ $\frac{1}{x}$  is small and $\frac{1}{\theta}<\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Thanks! Will accept when it permits me to in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x \ge q$. Apply the MVT to $f(t) = \log(t)$ on the interval $[x,y]$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying LMVT to the function $\ln x$, we have, for some  $r\in (x,y)$, $$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{\ln y-\ln x}{y-x}$$ Now, choose $x$ such that $q\le x$, then, $$\frac{1}{q}\ge \frac{1}{r}=\frac{\ln y-\ln x}{y-x}$$